# Can one differentiate cases when returning an HTTP 422 in a REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api-design

I am developing a REST API in Rails.

The API returns an HTTP 422 unprocessable entity with error messages when model validations fail.

However, a model can have several validations and I want to delegate the translation of the error messages to the API consumer and that is why it needs to differentiate what was the specific cause for the server to return a 422.

I was thinking about using subcodes, just like Facebook does in its API. Is there a way to do this keeping the REST practices?

Also, what does one do when an error 422 occurs for multiple causes at the same time?

Comment: can you post your error here?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)

> Client Error 4.x.x
>
> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

Normally, you should encode information that is specific to your domain in the message-body of the response.  The status line and response headers are there for generic components (browsers, caches, proxies) to have a coarse understanding of what is going on.

The [Problem Details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) specification lays out the concern rather well.

> consider a response that indicates that the client's account doesn't have enough credit.  The 403 Forbidden status code might be deemed most appropriate to use, as it will inform HTTP generic software (such as client libraries, caches, and proxies) of the general semantics of the response.
>
> However, that doesn't give the API client enough information about why the request was forbidden, the applicable account balance, or how to correct the problem.  If these details are included in the response body in a machine-readable format, the client can treat it appropriately; for example, triggering a transfer of more credit into the account.

I don't promise that `Problem Details` is well suited for your purposes; but as prior art it should help you to recognize that the information you want to communicate belongs in the body of the response, with a suitable `Content-Type` header to inform the consumers which processing logic they need to use.